# How does "detection risk" work after update 13?

Tags: payday-2

Before, we established that [visibility is discrete](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129473/20306). With update 13, however, there is now a number called "detection risk". What does this number mean? How does a lower value affect my visibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the "detection risk" is the level that the detection meter starts at the moment a guard or camera spots you. So if you have a detection risk of 75, the highest, you will be detected very shortly after a guard or camera spots you.

In this screenshot, my detection risk is 35. The screenshot was taken on the same frame that the camera first noticed me (taken as a clip from a video):

[image: The detection meter starts at 35]

In order to successfully stealth, you're going to want that number to be reasonably low. Around 20 is usually good for me. The lower the better, though.

Comment: Also, interesting note from Update 13: Cameras *will* notice you in casing mode. Full stop. Whether or not they detect you depends on your detection risk, and how long you stay in their view.